# How to control the execution flow of c program through a config file. This file is passed using redirection operator (<)

Tags: c

I have a c program running. I want to make the program sleep for certain period say 5 sec. I want this sleep to be induced from a text file containing command "sleep(5)". I want to pass this file through redirection operator (<) while executing the program

say ./a.out < samplefile.txt

This samplefile.txt contains sleep(5) command in it. I tried the above scenario but the c program is reading it as stream of characters like s,l,e,e,p which is not our intention.

could some one please help me on this issue.

Comment: C is a compiled language - what you're trying to do will be non-trivial, arguably even *difficult* in C.  Why not use a language that better supports what you're attempting to do?

Answer (score 1):

You may make your program read the commands from the text file, parse them and behave as the commands say.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of parsing, you may use the environment variables.

In your program, call to [getenv](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/getenv/) in any place requires configuration. When calling to the program, make sure the environment is set with the required variables, or use this notation:

```
VAR1=VALUE1 VAR2=VALUE2 ./a.out
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very clear what you want to achieve, but this may be a prompt.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char buf[512];

    scanf("%s", buf);

    if (!strcmp(buf, "sleep(5)")) {
        printf("sleep...\n");
        sleep(5);
    }

    printf("over\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Imho that will not work as it's not a shellscript, but C.
He needs to parse '<', open file @ argv[2], then he can parse stuff out of it and do call sleep using system() or C library functions.